# Apache Ivy multiple resolvers

Tags: ant, ivy

Trying to get IvyRoundUp packager repository and cukes maven repository to work with chain resolvers in apache ivy

using the following

```
<settings defaultResolver="roundup"/>
<resolvers>
    <chain name="resolvers">
        <url name="cukes" m2compatible="true">
            <artifact
                    pattern="http://cukes.info/maven/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        </url>

        <packager name="roundup" buildRoot="${user.home}/.ivy2/packager/build"
                  resourceCache="${user.home}/.ivy2/packager/cache">
            <ivy pattern="http://ivyroundup.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/modules/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>
            <artifact
                    pattern="http://ivyroundup.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/modules/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/packager.xml"/>
        </packager>
    </chain>
</resolvers>
```

now when i run ivy:retreive in my ant build it comes up with

```
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]          module not found: cuke4duke#cuke4duke;0.1.6
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== roundup: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://ivyroundup.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/modules/cuke4duke/cuke4duke/0.1.6/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact cuke4duke#cuke4duke;0.1.6!cuke4duke.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    http://ivyroundup.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/modules/cuke4duke/cuke4duke/0.1.6/packager.xml
[ivy:retrieve]          module not found: org.jruby#jruby-complete;1.4.0RC1
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== roundup: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://ivyroundup.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/modules/org.jruby/jruby-complete/1.4.0RC1/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact org.jruby#jruby-complete;1.4.0RC1!jruby-complete.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    http://ivyroundup.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/modules/org.jruby/jruby-complete/1.4.0RC1/packager.xml
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]          ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]          :: cuke4duke#cuke4duke;0.1.6: not found
[ivy:retrieve]          :: org.jruby#jruby-complete;1.4.0RC1: not found
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]
```

from what i can make out from the ivy website this means i have 2 resolvers and ivy should check both repositories what am I missing, as its not hitting the cukes resolver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the solution is

```
<settings defaultResolver="chain-1"/>
<resolvers>
    <packager name="roundup" buildRoot="${user.home}/.ivy2/packager/build"
              resourceCache="${user.home}/.ivy2/packager/cache">
        <ivy pattern="http://ivyroundup.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/modules/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>
        <artifact
                pattern="http://ivyroundup.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/modules/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/packager.xml"/>
    </packager>
    <chain name="chain-1">
        <resolver ref="roundup"/>
        <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true" usepoms="true"/>
        <url name="cukes" m2compatible="true">
            <artifact
                    pattern="http://cukes.info/maven/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        </url>
    </chain>
</resolvers>
```